# Could the first part of a url resolve to machine X but if you add a path it would resolve to machine Y?

Tags: apache, http, web-applications, ip, virtualhost

If I have a url like this:
`http://somehostname/` that is a machine `X` and I press on a link of the page and I see on the browser the url:
`http://somehostname/application` is it possible that this url actually is served by a different machine `Y` despite the fact that the first part of the `url` **always** resolves in the machine `X`?
This is impossible in some servers e.g. tomcat, but is it possible in others? E.g. apache?

Comment: It is possible, but somewhat burdensome, as `somehostname` would have to act as a proxy, so you'd have double the traffic etc. People usually use subdomains for this because it's easier

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

`http://somehostname/application` means, "connect, using the http protocol, to the server called somehostname, and as for /application". The closes thing to this would be that the server can use a `redirect` (saying, "no, you want to go to that machine instead"), or the server could `proxy` the request - without telling the web browser, go out and get the page from elsewhere, and then present it to the browser as if the page was it's own.

Comment: Why? I think that `VirtualHost` is something similar to this. Also what if `somehostname` is some vip or a hostname that resolves in multiple IPs?

Comment: If a dns name resolves to multiple IPs, the web browser will pick one of them (at random, I think); if the connection to that web server fails, then it will try another. `VirtualHost` is the reverse - the webserver at the ip in question will be told what server was asked for, and will make a decision based on this as to what to return. A connection to a vip will still, eventually, connect to a single machine (again, this machine may make a decision on what to do next, including passing it on to another machine).

Comment: What if there is e.g. a load balancer or some kind of proxy?

Comment: A load balancer balances load, and (usually) does not divide up requests based on the requested URL. A proxy server can do it [technically this would normally be a 'reverse proxy', being close to the server, rather than a normal proxy, which is close to the client]. I did mention in my post that the webserver could proxy specific requests on to other machines - a reverse proxy is a special case of this, where it proxies ALL requests to one or more other servers. A reverse proxy is, by definition, a webserver (which happens to return content based on requests passed on to other servers).